# Bound text of a TextBox different to bound "item" possible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

XAML

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding SelectedKey.Name}" />
```

I want to bind an instance of `SelectedKey` to a TextBox, but show the property `SelectedKey.Name` as text.

How is this possible? I could not find a TextBox property like "DataBoundItem".

Comment: Are you facing any error ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `DataContext` of the `TextBlock` has a property called "SelectedItem" that returns an object with a `SelectedKey` property you could bind to the `Name` property of this latter one like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.SelectedKey.Name}" />
```

If you want to bind to the `SelectedKey` property of an item that is currently selected in an `ItemsControl` such as for example a `ListBox`, you could use an `ElementName` binding:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ... />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.SelectedKey.Name, ElementName=listBox1}" />
```

If you need any further help you should read this:

[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

> I could not find a TextBox property like "DataBoundItem".

A `TextBox` doesn't have any "DataBoundItem" property. It has a `Text` property for displaying the text in the `TextBox` and that's it basically.

All controls that inherit from `FrameworkElement` has a `Tag` property of type `object` that you can bind anything you want to though. You can use this one:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedKey.Name}" Tag="{Binding SelectedKey}" />
```